# javascript scope pitfall with setTimeout and bind

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

For the following code, I'm expecting "Jupiter" for the console 2 and 3, but getting the one bound to the global window object, even though I passed a different context.

```js
function otherScope () {
  this.sectionHeight = "Jupiter"
}

(function () {
    var sectionHeight = "Mars";
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('console 1', sectionHeight)
      })
    }())
}())

window.sectionHeight = "cool!";

(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', sectionHeight)
  })
}.bind(otherScope)())


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 3', sectionHeight)
}.bind(otherScope))


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 4', sectionHeight)
})
```

Comment: Don't confuse the `this` keyword (the context, or "call receiver") with variable scopes.

Comment: Whatever you define to be `this` (with bind) will not have any impact on unqualified variable references. You need to do `this.sectionHeight`, if you want to get to the property of whatever `this` is.

Comment: if i remember well, setTimeout is always executed from the global context, so i have really no idea what can come from this bind..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te otherScope is a function and is not a Object with properties. You have to do a `new` for this. So:

```
var x = new otherScope();
x.sectionHeight;
```

Next, the scope of this only reaches the current scope. The setTimeout creates a new scope. Therefor we need to do another binding. Or creating a variable inside the first scope outside the setTimeout.

Some example (variable within scope):

```
(function () {
  var theScope = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', theScope.sectionHeight)
  });
}.bind(new otherScope())())
```

Some example (another bind):

```
(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', this.sectionHeight)
  }.bind(this)); // Pass the context to the new scope
}.bind(new otherScope())())
```

Comment: Totally get it now! I had some assumptions in mind and was refreshing some basics (as I do, from time to time) and got stuck on this one when I shouldn't! Thanks a lot for your explanation, makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

`bind` sets the value of `this` for the function on which it is called (which I shall refer to as `x`).

It does not:

- Affect anything about a different function (`y`) even if `y` is called *by* `x`
- Affect the variables that are in scope for `x` or any function called by `x`.

There is no way to change the scope that a function exists in. That is determined solely by where it is declared.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Niels uses `otherScope` as a **constructor function** with `new`, which is a great solution for your specific problem. But be aware that JavaScript is a very flexible language, so there are many possible alternatives...

You could:

1. Add a "static" own property to `otherScope`
2. Add a property to the prototype of `otherScope`
3. Return an object literal in `otherScope`

etc.

### Static own property

```js
function otherScope () {}
otherScope.sectionHeight = "Jupiter";

(function () {
    var sectionHeight = "Mars";
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('console 1', sectionHeight);
      });
    }());
}());

window.sectionHeight = "cool!";

(function () {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', that.sectionHeight);
  });
}.bind(otherScope)());


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 3', this.sectionHeight);
}.bind(otherScope));


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 4', sectionHeight);
});
```

### Prototype property

```js
function otherScope () {}
otherScope.prototype.sectionHeight = "Jupiter";

(function () {
    var sectionHeight = "Mars";
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('console 1', sectionHeight);
      });
    }());
}());

window.sectionHeight = "cool!";

(function () {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', that.sectionHeight);
  });
}.bind(otherScope.prototype)());


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 3', this.sectionHeight);
}.bind(otherScope.prototype));


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 4', sectionHeight);
});
```

### Object literal

```js
function otherScope () {
  return {sectionHeight: "Jupiter"};
}

(function () {
    var sectionHeight = "Mars";
    (function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('console 1', sectionHeight);
      });
    }());
}());

window.sectionHeight = "cool!";

(function () {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('console 2', that.sectionHeight);
  });
}.bind(otherScope())());


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 3', this.sectionHeight);
}.bind(otherScope()));


setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('console 4', sectionHeight);
});
```